# How to filter items by product size in Algolia

Tags: algolia

I'm new to Algolia. I have loaded up about 1000 products and I've added a few attributes for faceting, e.g. Brand, Category.

However, each of my products comes in multiple sizes, and I want to provide the user with a range filter (or checkbox filter) for this. All products will come in one or more of sizes 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16. How can I set up Algolia to allow for this? It doesn't seem to have support for multi-value fields.

Help much appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Algolia does support multi-value fields.

This wasn't immediately obvious. I discovered this after coming across this page:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/filtering-faceting#filtering
which demonstrates using square brackets to list multiple tags.

I manually edited a couple of products' JSON, added a new "Sizes" field and listed the sizes in the same format as shown for tags.
E.g.

```
"Sizes": [
  10,
  12,
  14
]
```

I then added Sizes to the list of faceted fields. The list of Sizes and their product counts then appeared on the left when browsing the Index within Algolia. Exactly what I needed.

[image]